# How to Add SSL for Wordpress Multisite Domain Mapping

Tags: wordpress, ssl, dns, multisite

I have successfully set up Wordpress Multisite, using subfolders. I can clone an existing site, however when I try to map it to a new domain, I get an SSL error. This makes sense, because the new domain doesn't have an SSL certificate set up, but I don't know how to properly do this.

My setup is that I'm using forge.laravel.com over digitalocean.com

**MY DILLEMMA:**

My multisite address: multi.myprimarydomain.com - WORKS

My cloned multisite site: multi.myprimarydomain.com/cloned-site - WORKS

My desired domain for the cloned site: mysecondarydomain.com - ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

**STEPS I'VE TAKEN:**

1. I pointed my GoDaddy IP for mysecondarydomain.com to the server with
   multi.myprimarydomain.com.
2. I changed the Site Address (URL) to mysecondarydomain.com in the WP Multisite Admin section for multi.myprimarydomain.com/cloned-site.

I know I have to somehow install an SSL Cert for mysecondarydomain.com, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Forge offers free SSL certificates from Let's Encrypt. You can check their [official resource](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/sites/ssl.html) and follow the installation guide. You'd have to install separate certs for each site, but this shouldn't be an issue, as Forge offers automatic renewals.